# Mock Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() in Android Unit Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric

I want to mock the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and point it to *"C:\Users\\Android-Test\"*. I tried both of below options but nothing worked:

1. Mocked the `RuntimeEnvironment.application` thinking that it will also mock the `Environment` but it didn't.

```
File filesDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Android-Test\\" + application.getPackageName());
RuntimeEnvironment.application = spy(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
when(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext()).thenReturn(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
when(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getFilesDir()).thenReturn(filesDir);
```

2. Used ShadowEnvironment

```
ShadowEnvironment.setExternalStorageState(filesDir, Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)
```

P.S. I need to unit test copying/deleting of files without the use of emulator or devices, so I'm using `Robolectric`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using Temporary Folder for this.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Environment.class)
public class ExternalStorageTest() {

   @Rule
   TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

   @Before
   public void doSetup() {
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(Environment.class);

      when(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()).thenReturn(tempFolder.newFolder());
   }

}
```